# How to mass-create maps with different features centered?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cartography, template

Can anyone explain if this is something that can be done? I have map consisting of a little under 40,000 acres. I would like to print a map based on the legal location with each section being centered on a separate map at a scale of 1:1,000, for a total of 130 individual maps. Each map will have the same data, the only thing that will change from map to map is the feature that is centered.

Is it possible to have arc auto-create a map for each feature? I am using ArcMap 10.1 for desktop.

Comment: Have you looked at [Data Driven Pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/what-are-data-driven-pages-.htm)?

Comment: Here is a link to the same [Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003m000000) resource for 10.1 (previous link is for 10.3)

Comment: Definitely sounds like a use case for Data Driven Pages to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Data Driven Pages (DDP).  Here is a basic guide for setting up DDP in ArcMap.

I have started with some random polygons and points I created
[image]

Turn on the Data Driven Pages toolbar (Customize > Toolbars > Data Driven Pages) and click on the Setup button
[image]

In the Set Up Data Driven Pages dialog, select the layer you want to loop through (can be a page grid, or any other layer), and if you have any of the extra fields in that layer, such as Rotation, Page Number, etc. you can specify them in this dialog.  If not you can leave them blank.  Setting these can give you a bit more control over how your pages are displayed.
[image]

On the next tab you can set your scale settings - easiest option here, if you want them all at 1:1000, is to just choose Center and Maintain Current Scale, and then you can set your layout scale to 1:1000 and it'll keep it at that.  Alternatively you can play around with the other options here for potentially better results.
[image]

On my Layout I have added scale text and from the Insert menu I have added some dynamic text which references a field I specified from within my polygon layer.  This will display the text from that field for the polygon that is displayed on each page.
[image]

And the end result is a number of pages that pan to each record as I step through them (using the buttons on the DDP toolbar), and the text updates for each new page.
[image]

ArcMap can automatically step through each page when you export or print your map.  This is done using the Pages tab in Export Map dialog's Options section, or the Data Driven Pages section of the Print dialog

Export Map options:
[image]

Print dialog options:
[image]